# Clipboard empty after computer wakes up from sleep (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: 20.04, clipboard, copy, paste, copy-and-paste

I copy something to the clipboard and I close my laptop. When I open it and log in, the clipboard is empty.

Is this intended? I have muscle memoy from Windows that the computer should remember what was in the clipboard after waking up fro m sleep.

Comment: I guess it is a security feature of the lockscreen to empty clipboard. Otherwise you could have the password in the clipboard and anybody could remove the lockscreen just by pasting the password.

Comment: @Marco, the clipboard of a user will not be available at the login screen, but yes, it could be a security feature of the lock screen. I have lock screen disabled, and for me, the clipboard is still there when resuming from sleep.